# Can I overwrite default Magento configuration?

Tags: shipping, configuration

in my local.xml I have the chance to configure, for example, the secure and unsecure URLs for specific shop setups. So I don't have to configure these settings in the database. That makes migration and version management of the code much easier.

My question is if I can overwrite other settings, like shipping/origin, in the default config.xml? My example don't work, only one setting was accepted.

Example of config.xml (identical in all my application realms)

```
<config>
 ...
 <default>
  <shipping>
  <origin>
   <country_id>DE</country_id>
   <region_id>82</region_id>
   <city>Berlin</city>
  </origin>
  </shipping>
 </default>
</config>
```

In this example only  is recognized in Magento-Admin-Backend, the other nodes not.

Have anybody an idea why this is happend?

Thanks and Greetings,
Pat

Comment: have you need to add custom fields or updates exiting fields in default Magento configuration?

Comment: Hi, I want to update existing fields. I want to have all my config in XML files and not only in database because of versioning and better migration. thx